# Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'remoteMessageDelegate'

Tags: swift, firebase

when i update firebase pods get bellow error:

> Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'remoteMessageDelegate'

```
 //notification

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self as? MessagingDelegate

    }
```

how i can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
// For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

 let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
options: authOptions,
completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
 UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], 
categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/dc2cd2db6e82e5c475fa3f0efe75df8b54f04544/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55

Comment: The answer is incorrect. `Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate` has been moved to `Messaging.messaging().delegate`. The code snippet above misses the line that is the actual fix for the original issue.